# 3DS Friend Registration: "You cannot use Internet registration because you are not online". How to fix?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

In the Nintendo 3DS Friends app, I'm trying to register a new friend.

In the Friends app, I click the orange "Add friend" icon, then in the dialog that appears with the choices "Local" and "Internet", I tap "Internet".

At this point, I get the error: "You cannot use Internet registration because you are not online."

The status bar on the top screen of the 3DS does show "Internet", indicating that I *am* online.  I can successfully use the 3DS to do other online things such as browse the e-shop.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your router's security settings, you need to forward UDP ports 9103 and 50000-60000 to your 3DS.

Source: http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/wfc/en_na/ds/results.jsp?error_code=001-0502&system=3DS